# Attaching Event to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working at my 'To Do List'. My goal is to create an 'delete' button inside previously created div, which contains note written by user.

The problem is that I can't use Jquery - click() because it doesn't work with dynamically created elements.

I tried to use on(), but it causes that 'delete' button appears in every note I made.

```js
var ammleng;
var amount = [];

function ammcheck() {
  if (amount.length == 0) {
    return amount.length;
  } else {
    return amount.length++;
  }
}

function Start() {
  var start = document.getElementsByClassName('start')[0];
  start.style.display = 'none';
  var textarea = document.getElementsByClassName('textarea')[0];
  textarea.classList.remove('locked');
  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn__container')[0];
  btn.classList.remove('locked');
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0];
  text.classList.add('after');
  $('.notes').slideDown(2000);
}

function add() {
  var txtarea = document.getElementsByClassName('textarea')[0];
  ammleng = amount.length;
  if (ammleng >= 13) {
    alert('Za dużo notatek!')
  } else if (txtarea.innerText.length < 1) {
    alert('Nic nie napisałeś :(');
  } else {
    amount[ammcheck()] = document.getElementsByClassName('note');
    var text = $('.textarea').html();
    var cont = document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0];
    var ad = document.createElement('div');
    var adding = cont.appendChild(ad);
    adding.classList.add('note');
    adding.innerText = text;
    txtarea.innerText = '';
  }
}

function reset() {
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0];
  els.innerHTML = '';
  amount = [];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='logo'>
    To Do List
  </div>
  <div class='text'>
    <button class='start' onclick='Start()'>Zaczynajmy</button>
    <div class='textarea locked' contenteditable='true' data-text='Wpisz notkę...'></div>
    <div class='btn__container locked'>
      <button class='dodaj' onclick='add()'>Dodaj</button>
      <button class='resetuj' onclick='reset()'>resetuj</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='notes'></div>
</div>
```

I tried to make it this way, but it return an error (...'appendChild() is not a function...')

```
var del = document.createElement('div');
        del.classList.add('del');

        $('.notes').on('click', '.note', function(){
            $(this).appendChild(del);
            })
```

Comment: you need to put your code in your post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `on()` is what you need to use. Your description of why it doesn't work makes very little sense. We need to see your code to help you debug it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use already existing `document` to bind click on

```
        $(document).on('click', '.note', function(){
            $(this).appendChild(del);
        })
```